# I dont understand why this python code is not working

Tags: python, list

Basically i want to make a program in python that, given a list of words and a list of letters, it will print out a list with only the words that don't contain any letter in the list of letters.

```
lista = ["computador","comida","atum","pai","porco","amigo","bloco","carro","banana","janela","calculadora","caneca","prato","livro","jogo","fabrico","cruz","pedra","ar","vento"]
letras_prib = ["a","b"]
for palavra in lista:
    for letra in letras_prib:
        if letra in palavra:
            listafinal = lista.remove(palavra)
print(listafinal)
```

Here you can see the list of words is:

```
lista = ["computador","comida","atum","pai","porco","amigo","bloco","carro","banana","janela","calculadora","caneca","prato","livro","jogo","fabrico","cruz","pedra","ar","vento"]
```

And the list of letters is:

```
["a","b"]
```

My problem is, when i run this exact program, it just prints out "None". From my understanding it should be printing out every word that does'nt contain the letter "a" or "b".
I really need help as i've searched a lot but still have no idea how to fix this.
PS: If you have trouble understanding some portuguese words;

palavra = word

lista = list

listafinal = finallist

letra = letter

letras_prib = prohibited letters.

And yes, there ARE words in the list that don't contain the letter "a" or the letter "b", like "porco" for example.

Comment: `.remove` returns `None`

Comment: @KrishnaChaurasia but i set the final list to the list, except with its "word"element removed, I still dont understand why it doesnt work

Comment: Note that you are changing the list you are currently iterating over: that can lead to (other) bugs, and should be avoided.

Comment: @Sayse so how would i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.remove` doesn't return a new list with the item removed, it removes it inplace and returns none

Instead, start your final list as a copy of the original and then just remove without assigning to a variable

```
listafinal = lista[:]  # When declaring listafinal
...
listafinal.remove(palavra)  # Where you're currently removing
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `del` to remove element from the list.
And while iterating through list iterate from the last so removing elements from last will remove all the elements.
Check below code:

```
lista = ["computador", "comida", "atum", "pai", "porco", "amigo", "bloco", "carro", "banana", "janela", "calculadora",
         "caneca", "prato", "livro", "jogo", "fabrico", "cruz", "pedra", "ar", "vento"]
letras_prib = ["a", "b"]

for palavra in lista[::-1]:
    for letra in letras_prib:
        if letra in palavra and palavra in lista:
            del lista[lista.index(palavra)]
print(lista)
```